# C++ converting from string array to int array without crashing the program

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm trying to find the simplest way to convert a string array of numbers to an int array so that I can use it in calculations. Stringstream and stoi have so far both crashed the program or not worked. Any help? Thanks!

```
int counter = 0;
string nums[51];
while (! rel.eof())
{       
    getline(rel, tuple);
    cout<<tuple<<endl;
    //minituple[counter] = tuple.substr(0,4);
    //counter++;
    istringstream iss(tuple);

    do
    {
        string found_num;
        iss >> found_num;

        if (iss.fail())
            break;

        char goaway;
        goaway = found_num.at(0);
        if (goaway == '\n')
            counter--;
        else if (goaway == ' ')
            counter--;
        {
            nums[counter] = found_num;
            cout << "Substring: " << found_num << endl;
        }
        counter++;
    } while (iss);      
}

int int_nums[51];
for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)
{
    if (!nums[i].empty())
    {
        stoi(nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried which crashed the program.

Comment: You can edit your question using [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33891808/edit).

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the entire error so that we can diagnose your issue.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)` This will have UB when i = 51. Since `int int_nums[51];` and `string nums[51];` are valid for indices 0..50

Comment: That one got it working, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Once you've loaded your strings array you could just do:

```
std::transform(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums), std::begin(int_nums), 
               [](auto const &str) { return std::stoi(str); });
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11bc7208025bbf70)